# Security setting issue in salesforce-OWD

Tags: security, owd

I have a requirement on admin part.

I have a profile called vetprofile where the users of the profile needs to see only specific records of an object which have assigned to field value is equal to some queue that is vetqueue.

The remaining users of all profiles except vetprofile in the org should be able to see/share  all records or should have the public read/write type behaviour between them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should assign the OWD as `Private` to that object.

To expose the record visibility to the queue members, create public group based on which queue has been created.

Write criteria based sharing rule to expose the `Read Only` visibility to those vetprofile users.

For rest of the members, create a separate public group and assign `Read Write` access.

To create the public groups you can use `Roles and Internal Subordinates` rather than assigning individual users to the group.

Comment: For Vet profile users I have created a Role  in order to separate him from the others users hierarchy as vet user is an external user.In order to assign remaining users to public group as u suggested if I take Roles and Internal Subordinates top most hierarchy , will all the users be assigned to the public group?Please suggest